# How to find extreme point in Banach Algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $X$ is Banach Algebra, $Y$ is subspace of $X$ and $A = \big \{ f \in X^* , \Vert f\Vert\leqslant1,f(xy)=f(yx) , x \in X, y \in Y \big\}$ and $A$ separates the points in $X$. How we can show there is no a point $x_0 \in X$ that isn't zero, with this property: for every $f\in A$, if $f(x_0)$ doesn't equal zero, then there are $g,h$ in $A$ such that $f =(g+h)/2$ .

Comment: Parsing help: Show that for each $x_0$ there exist $g,h\in A$ such that $g(x_0)+h(x_0)\not = 0$

Comment: Could you explain more? Thank you

Comment: What I wrote is just a reformulation of what you wrote, isn't it?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: The statement you are now looking for is wrong (it is the opposite of the statement I wrote in my first comment (both are probably missing the requirement $g\not =h $)). Are you missing some requirement about boundary points?

Comment: This is correct, yes?

Comment: What is correct?

Comment: I'm still not sure what exactly you're looking for, but for what I currently see in your question, take any $f\in A$ with $f(x_0)\not=0$ and define $g:=1/3f$, $h:=2/3f$